# React Native v0.62 upgrade increase iOS .ipa size

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa

I recently upgraded from RN v0.60.5 to RN v0.62.2 and I noticed that my iOS builds are now producing an .ipa file nearly triple in size, from ~50MB to 130MB. I can't seem to find any reason for this. I'm guessing it has something to do with Flipper, but I have no evidence of this - simply a guess. I do have several images and fonts that I can probably be removed to decrease the overall size, but regardless, why would my builds produce such a huge increase in size? I can't seem to find any reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the reason for such a huge increase in build size is due to the inclusion of Flipper with v0.62.x. Flipper has a dependency on the Swift Framework, which is rather large. To decrease the build size, I had to remove the Flipper install from my podfile and Flipper related code in the AppDelegate.m file.